# setTimeout inside mocha test doesn't work

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, coffeescript, mocha.js

I am using a function that goes like the following. I am using async series to test asynchronous functions. The first callback in the series is working absolutely fine and it all breaks at this second method named callThisGuy(client, callback)

```
testFunction: () ->
  client = @
  ASync.series([
    (callback) ->
       client.createSingleClient(callback)
    (callback) ->
       client.callThisMethod(client, callback)
    (callback) ->
      trace "In the next step"
  ],
 (err, results) ->
     trace "Test"
 )
```

Here is the callThisMethod function

```
callThisMethod:(client, callback) ->
    if(client.status == "new")
        callback(null," ")
    else
        setTimeout ( ->
            client.callThisMethod(client, callback)
        ), 1000
```

The setTimeout function is never called even when the status is not "new". It instead skips to the next step. I ran the same code without Mocha and then the timeout works fine.

Inside mocha, it is not working. I also checked if setTimeout is undefined. It was defined. I wonder if I am missing something.

Comment: How exactly does mocha fit into this? Could you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of the issue? Have you [informed it that the test is asynchronous](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#asynchronous-code)?

Answer (score 5):

If I could only read coffeescript I could help more. So much ugly. :(

https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code

You'll need to specify a "done" callback method to your test function. Mocha uses the fact that you've declared a callback parameter to know if the test is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can make `setTimeout` work in a CoffeScript Mocha test:

```
describe 'This code', ->
  it 'should wait for myAsyncFunc', (done) ->
    this.timeout 4000
    myAsyncFunc = () ->
      console.log 'Tests here..'
      done()
    setTimeout myAsyncFunc, 3000
```

- The test `'should wait for myAsyncFunc'` will not wait for asynchronous calls if the callback function `done` is not specified.
- Note that `this.timeout 4000` avoids errors like: `Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.`
- More info about asynchrounous code in Mocha (JavaScript) here: http://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code